# How to set navbar and tabbar not transparent and their borders visible

Tags: swift, uikit, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I can not find any info in internet about this question. I have tableview in UIViewcontroller and it is embedded in navigation controller. I want that my navbar was always like in scrolling state (borders are visible) and same thing with tabbar. Here is photo what I have(1-st) and what I want (2-nd).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AppDelegate file in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method added:

```
        //MARK: - NavBar appearance
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "AccentColor")
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance  = navBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
        
        //MARK: - TabBar appearance
        let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "AccentColor")
        UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance  = tabBarAppearance
        UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
```